# PHP MySQL displaying messages according to multiple conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project in php/mysql but finding it difficult to move forward. Here is my case:

I have two tables 1st "users" and 2nd is "message". Table 1st contains userid,gender,age,city and country. 2nd table contains messageid,message,gender,minimum_age,maximum_age,city and country.

Now what I want to achieve is to show specific message to users which follow all conditions in message table. For example:

If I give conditions in message table like

```
==========================================================================
messageid || message    || gender || minimum_age || maximum_age || city || country

1            Messages 1    male      20             30             london  UK
2            Messages 2    female    ANY            40             gurgaon IN
```

My age is 24, gender is male, city is "london" and country is UK. Then I will see message "Message 1" on page. If none of condition match then i will see any message.

NOTE: Some users do not have age or city or country or gender in user database.

I need help in mysql query or best technique to accomplisg this task.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.userid, u.gender, u.age, u.city, u.country, m.messageid,
   m.minimum_age, m.maximum_age, m.city, m.country 
FROM users u, message m 
WHERE u.gender = m.gender and u.age between m.minimum_age and m.maximum_age 
     and u.city = m.city and u.country = m.country
```

something like that.

then check resultset, if empty, change query to select all messages

Comment: You want table.field, not field.table. Also, a JOIN may be more efficient.

Comment: Yeah true fixed. That was kinda lame. Regarding JOIN, i'd say that depends on how author creates a query. Sometimes I find it easier to create dynamic queries between tables without JOINs involved, unless there're performance issues. He can use prepared statements as well.

Comment: I have around 200,000 Users and visiting on website every second and many users do not have city or country or gender or age specified in table. I mean they havent filled their profile. Now if your query will result empty for one condition how to switch to next condition ..what will be logic??

Comment: what is an expected resultset in case one of conditions is false? should you display message or not?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is use [WHERE](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_WHERE_to_Filter_MySQL_Data) and [JOIN](http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/mysql_p5.php) in your SQL query.